# Deserializing json C#

Tags: c#, json, api, httpwebrequest

I have code that returns json data from a post api call. The data is in the below format:

```
{"data":[{"name":"123","pwd":123},{"name":"456","pwd":456},{"name":"789","pwd":789}]",duration":5309,"query":"myquery","timeout":300}
```

To deserialise the above json, I have written the following code:

```
Product myprod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(result);
var results = myprod.result;
```

My data remains null with count=0. Could anyone help me with where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. I'm guess the `,` should not be in `",duration"` instead before the name.

Comment: Use some tools like https://jsonutils.com/ for getting right class definitions.

Comment: Its better to build your classes corresponding to the json using [this](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: @Smartis . This question was asked earlier. So [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632107/deserialising-json-c-sharp) should be marked as duplicate. Or I don't understand something?

Comment: @IvanChepikov Maybe I got confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your json is invalid. Here is the same one but with fixes.

```
{"data":[{"name":"123","pwd":123},{"name":"456","pwd":456},{"name":"789","pwd":789}],"duration":5309,"query":"myquery","timeout":300}
```

And with this json model should look like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Datum[] data { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public string query { get; set; }
    public int timeout { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int pwd { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Basic naming issue by  the sub Item. `Datum` is not a suitable name.

Comment: @Smartis It is just example of classes structure. I think it is not a problem to rename a class or a property.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, you are right. I made a typo while entering the json. Your code returns data= mynamespace.Datum[0] instead of the correct data.

Comment: @Nilisha Do you use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(str);` I checked it right now and it works for me.

Comment: @Ivan, Yes, i have this : var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); Product myprod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result);

Comment: @Nilisha at least it should be Rootobject myprod = ... Here is my code. var str = "{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"123\",\"pwd\":123},{\"name\":\"456\",\"pwd\":456},{\"name\":\"789\",\"pwd\":789}],\"duration\":5309,\"query\":\"myquery\",\"timeout\":300}";
            var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(str); Check it first. It should work. Use models from the answer.

Comment: yes yes its Rootobject only, actually form me Rootobject is Prod so I changed it while writing here and forgot to change in one place.My code is : var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Product myprod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(result);

Answer (score 0):

DeserializeObject can not convert data struct to `IList<IList<string>>` .
You should implement [custom JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) yourself.