# Deserialising json C#

Tags: c#, json

I have json as below:

```
{"data":[{"name":"123","pwd":123},{"name":"456","pwd":456},{"name":"789","pwd":789}],"duration":5309,"query":"myquery","timeout":300}
```

Using http://json2csharp.com/ I am deserialising it as below:

```
 namespace Test 
   {
    public class Info
    {
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string pwd{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public Info[] data { get; set; }
        public int duration { get; set; }
        public string query { get; set; }
        public int timeout { get; set; }
    }
   //code here, function start etc.

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new 
    StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
     {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Product myprod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(result); 
            var results = myprod.data;
     }
}
```

The value of results is {Test.Info[0]} where Test is my namespace name. How do I obtain the actual data?

Comment: either you are posting wrong json, or you are posting wrong classes - it's not what http://json2csharp.com/ generates for given json

Comment: WTF the same question, twice a day? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627767/deserializing-json-c-sharp

Comment: Yes that's because I haven't found a solution yet, there was a mistype while writing question, apologies

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy you are right. I modifies the json and forgot to modify code. Updated. My issue is results value doesn't come up. I've put breakpoints in my code to see that the rest of the values are ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Info class should be

```
public class Info
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int pwd { get; set; }
    }
```

This should work

```
var testJson = "{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"123\",\"pwd\":123},{\"name\":\"456\",\"pwd\":456},{\"name\":\"789\",\"pwd\":789}],\"duration\":5309,\"query\":\"myquery\",\"timeout\":300}";

        var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(testJson);
```

Comment: Right. Sorry I had changed the json, updating the question